# Error on SQL query (nested select statement)

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am unsure as to why I am receiving a syntax error on the following SQL query.

The goal of the query (and the schema/created view listed later) is to find the names and company names of the managers that earn more money than the average salary of *all* the managers.

Here is the query I have written and the error that came with it:

```
select ManagerLastname, MFirstName, MMidInitial, company_name
  from ManagerInfo, Works
    (select avg(salary) as AverageManagerSalary, Lastname
     from Works,
     group by Lastname) Work1
where ManagerInfo.ManagerLastname = Work1.Lastname and
Works.salary > Work1.AverageManagerSalary;

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended : select ManagerLastname, MFirstName, MMidInitial, company_name from ManagerInfo, Works (select avg(salary) as AverageManagerSalary, Lastname from Works, group by Lastname) Work1 where ManagerInfo.ManagerLastname = Work1.Lastname and Works.salary > Work1.AverageManagerSalary
```

I am not sure where the syntax error is in this query. I thought that all the parentheses and "punctuation" were correct so I am thinking it's an issue with the nested *select* statement, but am unsure as to what would need to change within that statement...

Here is the overall schema for my database. This schema along with the above view I created "compiles" correctly so I know the error has to do with the query code itself.

```
create table Employee(
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    gender      char(1),
    street      varchar(10),
    city        varchar(10),
    primary key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial));

create table company(
    company_name    varchar(20),
    city    varchar(10),
    primary key(company_name));

create table Works(
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    company_name    varchar(20),
    salary      numeric(8,2),
    primary key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial, company_name),
    foreign key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial) references Employee,
    foreign key(company_name) references company);

create table Manages(
    Lastname    varchar(10),
    FirstName   varchar(10),
    MidInitial  char(1),
    ManagerLastname varchar(10),
    MFirstName  varchar(10),
    MMidInitial char(1),
    start_date  date,
    primary key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial, ManagerLastname, MFirstName, MMidInitial),
    foreign key(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial) references Employee);

create view ManagerInfo as
  (select distinct ManagerLastname, MFirstName, MMidInitial, street, city
   from Manages, Employee
   where Manages.ManagerLastname = Employee.Lastname and
  Manages.MFirstName = Employee.FirstName and
  Manages.MMidInitial = Employee.MidInitial);
```

By the way, I am using SQL for Oracle 11g R2.

Thanks for any help you can provide; much appreciated.

Comment: Comma after "Works" on line 2? I don't have oracle to check if that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a comma after Works in your from clause?  (The first one)  Then there appears to be an extra comma after Works in your subselect.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I had a feeling it would amount to something meticulous like that..